# Share / delete cookie across subdomain (www) in php

Tags: php, cookies, save, subdomain

I have a login/logout system and need the cookies to work across www.mydomain.com as well as mydomain.com. The problem I'm having is on deleting the cookies. On the login I am setting the cookies like this:

```
session_start();
//set session vars
setcookie('user_id', $row['user_id'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), '/', 'domain.com');
setcookie('full_name', $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), '/', 'domain.com');
```

Which works, and the cookies are saved and it works with or without the www. It allows the profile page to be viewed which has this code:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['full_name'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['full_name'] = $_COOKIE['full_name'];
}
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
echo '<p class="login">Please <a href="login.php">log in</a> to access this page.</p>';
exit();
}
```

The problem is logging out:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
$_SESSION = array();

if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 3600, '/', 'domain.com');
}

session_destroy();
}
setcookie('user_id', '', time() - 3600, '/', 'domain.com');
setcookie('full_name', '', time() - 3600, '/', 'domain.com');
```

The cookies are deleted but only for the current domain. So if I login from domain.com/login.php and logout from domain.com/logout.php, domain.com/profile.php doesnt work (good) but I will still be able to view www.domain.com/profile.php if I have visited the www. version before logging out. And vice versa I can logout from www.domain.com/logout.php and still be able to view domain.com/profile.php. Is there a way to delete all cookies across the subdomains?

Comment: Finally figured it out, the session was creating a separate cookie when the subdomain was changed. So logging out would delete one session cookie but leave the other. The solution was to name the session before starting it so it always has the same name:

    $some_name = session_name("cool_session");
    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
    session_start();

Answer (score 1):

Use '.domain.com' instead 'domain.com' to work with all subdomains.

Comment: I manually cleared all cookies from the browser (latest version of safari), and tried adding the .domain.com on the login cookies as well as logout cookies and the same thing still happens. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The OP wrote in a comment:

> Finally figured it out, the session was creating a separate cookie when the subdomain was changed. So logging out would delete one session cookie but leave the other. The solution was to name the session before starting it so it always has the same name:
>
> ```
> $some_name = session_name("cool_session");
> session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com'); session_start();
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)